# How do I execute a method in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

I'm trying to find the best way to execute a method in a Rails application.

I have the following in my model:

```
class Tweet < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch_all
    # do something
  end
end
```

I can go to my Rails console and run `Tweet.fetch_all` and it executes everything inside this method. However, I'd love to create an link in my application to execute this fetch inside the view. Would I need to create a new action inside my controller to get to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions are executed by controllers, so you need to define an action in tweets_controller.rb:

```
def fetch_all
 Tweet.fetch_all     #what do you want to do with this?
 redirect_to :back, notice: 'just called fetch_all'
end
```

and define a way to get to this action in routes.rb

```
post 'tweets/fetch_all', to: 'tweets#fetch_all'
```

Then you can use

```
<%= link_to 'Fetch all!', fetch_all_tweets_path, method: :post %>
```

anywhere in your views.

Comment: Or even better, in link_to use "remote: true" to do it smoothly with ajax

Comment: plz don't tell someone who hasn't RTFM-ed yet to use Ajax!! (And plz, OP, read your fine manual...)

Comment: Thank you, really kind of you to explain the rest of the setup. Really improved my understanding!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to create a separate link to execute this function, you will need to first create an action inside the controller for this purpose, and then later, you can create a helper method or simply, use `link_to` to place the link in your views.

Reason being that, if you add this method inside some other REST action, this `fetch` will be performed whenever that action is rendered, and this might not be what you intend.

Therefore, you should create another action that specifically executes this code for you, thereby, allowing you to **specifically** execute this method, whenever the user clicks that link.

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate the detail you've gone into. If I create a action called fetch and then inside just put Tweet.fetch_all I can then use <%= link_to 'Fetch', tweet, method: :fetch %> to execute this action which will execute my method?